# Security Concerns with Enabling Unrestricted PowerShell Remoting

Tags: security, powershell

I'd like to propose to the IT department at my organization that we enable PowerShell remoting on our production machines to make administering them easier.  I feel that unrestricted access would be much easier than dealing with signing:

```
>Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Is this a big no-no for production machines?  Would this open up a major security hole, or would it be safely restricted to those who already only have administrative privileges on the machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would go with `RemoteSigned` instead of `Unrestricted`. You can read about the differences [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347628.aspx).

This is the snippet that matters:

> -- RemoteSigned: Requires that all scripts and configuration files
>   downloaded from the Internet be signed by a trusted publisher.
>
> -- Unrestricted: Loads all configuration files and runs all scripts.
>   If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the Internet,
>   you are prompted for permission before it runs.

RemoteSigned will still let you run in-house scripts without signing, but items distributed via the Internet has to be signed.

All that being said, do you really need to run the actual scripts on the servers? If you're running management tasks from your workstation that modify a server, you don't need to set any of that. These settings only affect scripts run locally on the machine in question.

Comment: The reason I'd like to run the scripts on the machine is that they'll invoke old .js files that would be a hassle to rewrite and test in PowerShell.  Your answer was very helpful and I think RemoteSigned is the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: If you trust everyone all the time to the point that all users NEVER click on stuff and get PWN3D then it could be acceptable, but for the most part, always verify and then trust. Remember it's always one or the other, Secure OR convenient. It can't be both, it's a sliding scale between one or the other.